# Avoiding login activity on startup if password is cached

Tags: android

I have a typical Android app where the user has to log in before displaying the main Activity of the application. However, if we've already got a cached username / password, I want to skip the login page.

I could, in my Login `onCreate`, detect if I've got a user/pass and push a new Activity, but I'm worried that this will make my app startup slower (since I have to load an activity then immediately throw it away), and it also perhaps breaks the back button (i.e. you can hit back and end up back at the login screen).

Is there any way to avoid this and only load the full Login Activity if there is no cached password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a separate helper activity which launches either your login activity or your main activity. In its `onCreate`, you'd use `startActivity` and immediately call `finish` to remove the helper activity from the back stack.

```
Intent intent;
if ( /* already logged in */ ) {
    intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
} else {
    intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
}
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Then, `LoginActivity` should re-launch `MainActivity` as normal. This way, the user will never be able to navigate back to the helper activity as it does not appear in the back stack. Do note however that the user can still login, go to the `MainActivity`, pause that activity, remove his account (through the Android settings) and resume the activity (from the recent apps). If you want to prevent this, you're probably better off placing the login redirect in `MainActivity` instead (perhaps even in `onResume`).

Comment: That's what I do in my apps, I have a LoadingActivity, which is responsible for redirecting the user to the next activity. But you got to watch out for the Back-Stack as this LoadingActivity will appear there too

Comment: @HasTaiar It doesn't appear in the back stack if you call `finish()` on the helper activity immediately after redirecting.

Comment: Thanks @Mattias, did not know that :) I still use this LoadingActivity for other things too :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Splash Activity.

On the `AndroidManifest.xml`'s Splash Activity tag, add the `android:noHistory="true"`.

On the Splash Activity, check whatever you need (maybe with an `AsyncTask` if it may take a long time, to avoid freezing the Activity) and, depending on the result, you start the Login Activity or any other Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to transform login screen from `Activity` to `Dialog`. That should be easy. And then make your main activity check if there is cached username/password or not. In the second case show `LoginDialog` to user.

Answer (score 1):

I also have a typical Android app with the same requirement, and I solve it as follows.

First I configure the initial launch activity to be `MainActivity`, and then inside `onCreate()`, check if the user has saved credentials (this is all done through `AccountManager` and authenticator service).

If the check fails and user needs to authenticate, then I start the `LoginActivity`. If logging in fails or the user presses back, the `MainActivity` calls `finish()` on itself to close the whole app. Otherwise, after logging in, the `MainActivity` is resumed and is presented to the user properly.

The advantage of doing it in this order is that (in my case anyway) the user is more likely to be logged in than out, and so this will avoid any start/stopping of unneeded activities as you say.

A second advantage is that, if the `MainActivity` (or another activity) is resumed at a later time and the user's session has expired, you can simply start the `LoginActivity` again to reauthenticate them.

Hope that all makes sense :)